# contract.method.getData getData is undefined

Tags: contract-development, web3js

When I use `contract.method.getData(params)` it throws an error
*getData is undefined*. I searched on github and saw someone used request 
instead, and I used contract.method.request and it has successed!

Why getData is undefined with web3.js@0.20.1 and geth Version: 1.7.3-stable?

Comment: Your contract ABI seems not having the method name you are trying to call.

Comment: @Rajesh got it . i want to know that .request method`s result is a hex string , what it means ,do you know?

Comment: Whatever you interact with the ethereum blockchain will be of hex. Even getData yields the result in hex.

Comment: That sound like a bug. Are you using other framework like Truffle? Do you have the abi used?